# What is multiple re-inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I refer to the following as “multiple re-inheritance”:

- inheriting a class once directly and one or more times indirectly by inheriting one or more of its descendants
- inheriting a class indirectly two or more times by inheriting two or more of its descendants

I want to know if it exists and how to unambiguously access embedded subobjects.

1.) [*Professional C++*, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed.]<sup>†</sup> states a compilable program can't have a class that directly inherits both its immediate parent and said parent's parent class. Is it true?

Given a `GrandParent` and `Parent`, which extends `GrandParent`, VC12 and g++ allows a `GrandChild` to directly inherit from both `Parent` and `GrandParent`. In VC12 and g++, it’s possible to define these classes as follows:

`GrandParent` declares an `int num` data member. `Parent` declares its own `num` in addition to inheriting `GrandParent`'s `num`. `GrandChild` declares its own `num` in addition to inheriting `Parent`'s and `GrandParent`'s `num`s.

VC12 seems to allow unambiguous member access across the board, but g++ only allows it for some cases.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct GrandParent { int num; };
struct Parent : GrandParent { int num; };
struct GrandChild : GrandParent, Parent { int num; };

int main()
{
    GrandChild gc;
    gc.num = 2;
    gc.Parent::num = 1;
    gc.Parent::GrandParent::num = 0; // g++ error: ‘GrandParent’ is an ambiguous base of ‘GrandChild’
    gc.GrandParent::num = 5;         // g++ error: ‘GrandParent’ is an ambiguous base of ‘GrandChild’

                                                 // --VC12 output; g++ output--
    cout << gc.num << endl;                      // 2 ; 2
    cout << gc.Parent::num << endl;              // 1 ; 1
    cout << gc.Parent::GrandParent::num << endl; // 0 ; N/A due to above error
    cout << gc.GrandParent::num << endl;         // 5 ; N/A due to above error
}
```

2.) Why is (a) `gc.Parent::GrandParent::num` ambiguous in g++ when (b) `gc.Parent::num` isn't? (a) uniquely describes its location on the inheritance tree. `gc` only has 1 `Parent` subobject, which only has 1 `GrandParent` subobject, which only has 1 `num`. For (b), `gc` has one `Parent`, which has its own `num` but also a `GrandParent` subobject with another `num`.

3.) For `gc.GrandParent::num`, it seems VC12 looks into `gc`'s immediate `GrandParent` base subobject for the latter's `num`. I’m guessing the reason it is unambiguous is that it’s a name lookup qualified by `gc`, so the entity to the right of `.` is looked for first in `gc`'s scope, and the most immediate `GrandParent` to `gc`'s scope is the directly inherited one, not the indirectly inherited one via `Parent`. Am I wrong?

4.) Why is `gc.GrandParent::num` ambiguous to g++ when  `gc.Parent::num` isn't? If one is ambiguous, then shouldn't both be equally ambiguous? For the prior, `gc` has two `GrandParent`s; and for the latter, `Parent` has 2 `num`s.

---

<sup>†</sup>Gregoire, Marc R. et al. *Professional C++*, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. Indianapolis, IN: Wiley Pubishing, 2011. p. 241. Print.

Comment: *"[Professional C++, 2nd ed.]† states a compilable program can't have a class that directly inherits both its immediate parent and said parent's parent class. Is it true?"* No, that's wrong. The C++ Standard even contains an example and states there that it is well-formed, see [class.mi]/3 `class D : public A, public L { void f(); /∗ ... ∗/ }; // well-formed`, where `class A : public L { /∗ ... ∗/ };`

Comment: In the same paragraph, a note says: "A class can
be an indirect base class more than once and can be a direct and an indirect base class. There are limited
things that can be done with such a class. **The non-static data members and member functions of the direct
base class cannot be referred to in the scope of the derived class.**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: I think the reason why those accesses are ambiguous is that `GrandChild::Parent::GrandParent` is equivalent to `GrandChild::GrandParent` in terms of name lookup. Similarly, `struct A { int x; }; struct B : A {}; struct C : A {}; struct D : B, C {}; D d; d.B::A::x = 42;` fails.

Comment: *"how to unambiguously access embedded subobjects"* You could do that via something like `static_cast<Parent&>(gc).GrandParent::num = 42;`

Comment: +1 Interesting question. Adding to the mix of compilers, Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn), reports the same ambiguity errors as gcc.

Comment: You should be able to say `static_cast<Parent&>(gc).GrandParent::num` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common term for this is the *diamond pattern* (or [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)).

It is not an error per se, but as noted in the comments here, any attempt to access a direct base that is reduplicated elsewhere in the hierarchy will result in an ambiguity error.

One workaround would be to make the base indirect. The new inheriting constructors feature in C++11 allows perfect wrappers:

```
template< typename base, typename tag >
struct disambiguated_base : base
    { using base::base; };
```

Given an unused tag type, this generates a new class derived from, and functionally identical to, the given base. The tag type may be an incomplete class denoted by an elaborated-type-specifier:

```
struct GrandChild : Parent,
    disambiguated_base< GrandParent, class grandchild_grandparent_tag > {

    typedef disambiguated_base< GrandParent, grandchild_grandparent_tag >
        my_direct_grandparent;

    int num;
};
```

Now `GrandChild` can use `my_direct_grandparent::` to disambiguate member accesses.

Comment: +1. Ingenious. But, I wanted to access `GrandChild`’s `Parent`’s `GrandParent`, too. It’d be cumbersome to come up with another name like `grandchilds_parents_grandparent` for the elaborated-type-specifier, especially if the diamond gets more generations. Can it be indexed instead to allow `GrandChild.disambiguator<0>::` and `GrandChild.disambiguator<1>::`? i.e., can `disambiguated_base`’s type `tag` instead be a template template parameter, whose template parameter is an `int N`? How would the incomplete class template `foo<N>` be denoted in the elaborated-type-specifier? Thanks.

Comment: @CodeBricks Yeah, the tag can be anything, including a non-type, if you declare it that way. An incomplete specialization `Foo<N>` is called simply `Foo<N>`, but you do need to declare `template< int N > class Foo;`. You don't need disambiguation except to a direct base, though. `Parent::GrandParent::` works fine alongside `my_direct_grandparent::`.

Comment: *Meant to say `disambiguator<N>` instead of `foo<N>`. `gc.Parent::GrandParent::` gives g++ error. `GrandParent` is a direct base class of `GrandChild`. If I do
`template< typename base, template <int N> class tag > struct disambiguated_base`…
then how do I make the corresponding changes in the `GrandChild`'s inheritance statement for an incomplete, yet index-able, class template?
`struct GrandChild : Parent, disambiguated_base< GrandParent, class template<int N> class grandchild_grandparent_tag >` ?

Comment: You don't need to change any declarations, except to add the template forward declaration I mentioned in the last comment. Then use it as `struct GrandChild : Parent,
    disambiguated_base< GrandParent, disambiguator< 3 > > {`. The tag can be any typename, such as `int`, `string`, `class this_is_a_unique_name`, or `some_template< 42 >`.

Comment: @CodeBricks Automatically generating a tag is beyond the scope of this question, and may not be possible at all. Better to open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I’m adding to the accepted answer. It states a derived class cannot access a direct `base` class if the derived class also indirectly inherits `base`. Its solution makes the `base` class indirect by wrapping it with a template whose second type argument is `tag`. This ensures `base` is indirect to the derived class provided the derived class extends the wrapped base with a unique `tag`. The below example will use a non-type `tag`.

If the diamond-like problem were generalized to contain more generations in the form of:

- i<sup>th</sup> class inherits from `base` and (i – 1)<sup>th</sup>,
- (i – 1)<sup>th</sup> inherits from `base` and (i – 2)<sup>th</sup>,
- …, and
- 2<sup>nd</sup> inherits from `base`,

then it's an improvised container, where each element is stored in each uniquely tagged `base`. In that case, `tag`-making should be automated. One way is to consolidate all derived classes via a non-type template. Its non-type parameter `N` can specify the number of recursive inheritance iterations. By making `tag` a non-type parameter, the value of the parameter determining the number of subclasses can be uniquely related to that of the one tagging each subobject type. For example, `tag = 10` corresponds to `N = 10`, which refers to the 10th generation on the hierarchy:

// disambiguated_wrapper.h

```
struct int_wrapper {
    int num;
};

template < typename base, unsigned int tag >
struct disambiguated_wrapper : base {
    using base::base;
};
```

// improvised_container.h

```
#include "disambiguated_wrapper.h"

template <unsigned int N>
struct improvised_container : 
    protected disambiguated_wrapper<int_wrapper, N>, 
    protected improvised_container<N - 1> {

    unsigned int size() const { return N; }

    int& at(const unsigned int index) {
        if (index >= N) throw "out of range";
        else return (index == N - 1) ?
            this->disambiguated_wrapper<int_wrapper, N>::num :
            this->helper(index);
    }
protected:
    int& helper(const unsigned int index) {
        return (index == N - 1) ?
            this->disambiguated_wrapper<int_wrapper, N>::num :
            this->improvised_container<N - 1>::helper(index);
    }
};
#include "specializations.h"
```

// specializations.h

```
template <>
struct improvised_container<0> {
    improvised_container() = delete;
}; // ^ prohibits 0-length container

template <>
struct improvised_container<1> : 
    protected disambiguated_wrapper<int_wrapper, 1> {

    unsigned int size() const { return 1; }

    int& at(const unsigned int index) {
        if (index != 0) throw "out of range";
        else return this->disambiguated_wrapper<int_wrapper, 1>::num;
    }
protected:
    int& helper(const unsigned int index) {
        if (index != 0) throw "out of range";
        else return this->disambiguated_wrapper<int_wrapper, 1>::num;
    }
};
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "improvised_container.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    improvised_container<10> my_container;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < my_container.size(); ++i) {
        my_container.at(i) = i;
        std::cout << my_container.at(i) << ",";
    }   // ^ Output: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"
}
```

Element access `at` cannot decrement the `index` to recursively call itself, because `index` isn’t a compile-time constant. But `N` is. So, `at` calls `helper`, which recursively calls the (i – 1)<sup>th</sup> version of itself in the (i – 1)<sup>th</sup> subobject, decrementing `N` until it equals `index – 1`, with each call moving one scope deeper, and finally returning the element of the target scope. It checks against `index – 1` and not `index`, because the 0<sup>th</sup> `improvised_container` specialization's ctor is `delete`d. `at` compensates for the off-by-one.

`improvised_container` uses `protected` inheritance to prevent client code from accessing the `at` and `size` methods of its base subobjects. The subobject’s size is less than the enclosing object’s.

This works in g++ 4.8. The inheriting constructor `using base::base` causes errors in VC12, but it can be omitted because the element type is `int`.

Comment: Ah… I haven't totally grokked this yet, but it looks like you're implementing something like a `std::tuple`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I just added an explanation at the bottom. Honestly, I don't know `std::tuple`'s implementation.

Comment: Various implementations are possible including a chain of bases. The critical feature is that it returns a subobject given an index. Although your getter works at runtime, I think it could be adjusted to add a compile-time variant as well.

Comment: I don't understand that last comment… I'm not suggesting or criticising anything, just mentioning the similarity of implementation details to tuples.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you were interested in a compile time variant. Since `std::tuple` is already generally tuned to whatever compiler you're using, it's better not to reimplement it. Chain of bases isn't particularly efficient anyway. I have no idea what your use case is, I'm just mentioning similarities and answering questions in a vacuum, no context applied.