# Access modifier's different behaviors in inheritance depend on "this" keyword and templates or lack thereof

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, this, access-modifiers

I want to understand the access modifiers' 4 different behaviors regarding inheritance when it comes to the 4 combinations of using and/or omitting `template`s and the `this` keyword. All following code is done in g++ 4.8:

Here's a `GrandChild` class, which `private`ly inherits from `Parent`, which `private`ly inherits from `GrandParent`, which has a `public` `enum` `n`. Non-object, client code can access `GrandParent::n`, because the latter is a `public` `enum`. But `GrandParent::n` is inaccessible from within `GrandChild`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct GrandParent { enum {n = 0}; };

struct Parent : private GrandParent { enum {n = 1}; };

struct GrandChild : private Parent {
    enum {n = 2};
    void f() {cout << GrandParent::n << endl;}
    // ^ error: 'struct GrandParent GrandParent::GrandParent'
    // is inaccessible
};
int main() {
    cout << GrandParent::n << endl;
    // ^ non-object access would have outputted `0` had `GrandChild`'s
    // definition compiled or been commented out.
}
```

1.) Is `GrandParent::n`'s inaccessibility from within `GrandChild` caused by `GrandChild`'s possession of a `GrandParent` base subobject, which hides non-object access to `GrandParent::num`, and whose 2-generational `private`ness makes the base subobject’s `n` also inaccessible? I'd expected the error message to be about that.

2.) But apparently, it isn't. Why does the error complain about `GrandParent`'s constructor?

3.) Prepending `this->` to `GrandParent::n` in `f()`'s definition will add the error I expected in #1 but won't remove the ctor complaint. *Why?* I assumed that including `this->` is redundant and that its omission will cause the lookup to attempt to find the `n` of the `GrandParent` subobject within `GrandChild`'s scope before the less-immediately-scoped non-object `n` anyway.

4.) Why does this template variant compile? It seems functionally similar to the non-template one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <unsigned int N>
struct bar : private bar<N - 1> {
    enum {num = N};
    void g() {
        static_assert(N >= 2, "range error");
        cout << bar<N - 2>::num << endl;
    }
};

template <>
struct bar<0> { enum {num = 0}; };

int main() {
    bar<2> b2;
    b2.g(); // Output: 0
}
```

5.) Prepending `this->` to `bar<N - 2>::num` in `g()`'s definition causes the compiler error I expected in #1 only. But why doesn't it include the error of #2? And why doesn't its omission yield #2's error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole issue here is name lookup (I think this also has been the case [in one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20693848/420683)). I'll try to illustrate my understanding of what's happening:

Every (named) class gets an *injected-class-name*. For example:

```
struct GrandParent
{
    // using GrandParent = ::GrandParent;
    enum {n = 0};
};
```

You can use this injected-class-name to refer to the class itself. It is not that useful for ordinary classes (where unqualified lookup could find the name `GrandParent` in the surrounding scope anyway), but for derived classes and class templates:

```
namespace A
{
    struct Foo
    {
        // using Foo = ::A::Foo;
    };
};

struct Bar : A::Foo
{
    void woof(Foo); // using the injected-class-name `::A::Foo::Foo`
};

template<class T, int N, bool b>
struct my_template
{
    // using my_template = ::my_template<T, N, b>;
    void meow(my_template); // using the injected-class-name
};
```

This isn't inheritance as in "it's part of the base class subobject", but the way unqualified lookup is specified: If the name isn't found in the current class' scope, the base class scopes will be searched.

Now, for the first (non-template) example in the OP:

```
struct Parent : private GrandParent
{
    // using Parent = ::Parent;

    enum {n = 1}; // hides GrandParent::n
};

struct GrandChild : private Parent {
    // using GrandChild = ::GrandChild;

    enum {n = 2};
    void f() {cout << GrandParent::n << endl;}
    // ^ error: 'struct GrandParent GrandParent::GrandParent'
    // is inaccessible
};
```

Here, the expression `GrandParent::n` invokes unqualified name lookup of the name `GrandParent`. As unqualified lookup stops when the name is found (and doesn't consider surrounding scopes), it will find the injected-class-name `GrandParent::GrandParent`. That is, lookup searches the scope of `GrandChild` (name not found), then the scope of `Parent` (name not found) and finally the scope of `GrandParent` (where it finds the injected-class-name). This is done *before* and *independent of* access checking.

After the name `GrandParent` has been found, accessibility is checked eventually. Name lookup required to go from `Parent` to `GrandParent` to find the name. This path is blocked for anyone but members and friends of `Parent`, as the inheritance is private. (You can see through that path, but you may not use it; visibility and accessibility are orthogonal concepts.)

---

Here's the standardese [basic.lookup.unqual]/8:

> For the members of a class `X`, a name used in a member function body [...] shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>
> - before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block, or
> - shall be a member of class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X`, or
> - if `X` is a nested class of class `Y` [...]
> - [...]
> - if `X` is a member of namespace `N`, or [...], before the use of the name,
>     in namespace `N` or in one of `N`’s enclosing namespaces.

Name lookup in base classes is rather complicated as multiple base classes might have to be considered. For single inheritance and a member looked up in the scope of a member function body, it starts with the class which this function is a member of, and then traverses the base classes up (base, base of base, base of base of base, ..). See [class.member.lookup]

---

The template case is different, as `bar` is the name of a class template:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct bar : private bar<N - 1> {
    enum {num = N};
    void g() {
        static_assert(N >= 2, "range error");
        cout << bar<N - 2>::num << endl;
    }
};
```

Here, `bar<N - 2>` is used. It is a dependent name, as `N` is a template parameter. Name lookup is therefore postponed until the point of instantiation of `g`. The specialization `bar<0>` can be found, even it is declared after the function.

The injected-class-name of `bar` can be used as a template-name (referring to the class template) or as a type-name (referring to the current instantiation) [temp.local]/1:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected-
>   class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a *template-argument-list*,
>   as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-
>   specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent
>   to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.

That is, `bar<N - 2>` finds `bar` as the injected-class-name of the *current* class (instantiation). As it is used with a *template-argument-list*, it refers to another, unrelated specialization of `bar`. The injected-class-name of the base class is hidden.

`bar<0>::num` is accessed *not* through an access path that goes through a private inheritance, but directly through the injected-class-name of the current class, referring to the class template itself. `num` being a public member of `bar<0>` is accessible.

Comment: +1, accepted. Brilliant breakdown of name lookup and orthogonality between visibility and accessibility. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) subdivides qualification of an entire expression based on every name to right of a `::` punctuator: “…an unqualified name, that is name that does not appear to the right of a scope resolution operator…” Does this mean in `bar<N – 2>::num`, `num` is qualified, but `bar<N – 2>` is unqualified, so the latter doesn’t help find the subobject in `b2`?

Comment: @CodeBricks I'm not sure why you're talking about subobjects here. An object is a region of storage with some properties (such as a type). A name isn't a member of an object, it can be a member of a class. You're right that in `bar<N-2>::num`, `bar` is unqualified and `num` is qualified. Even if `num` were a non-static data member, first name lookup has to find it as a name (not as the object referred to by that name).

Comment: Doesn’t `b2` have a `bar<1>` base subobject, which has `bar<0>` base subobject? Meant to ask, for `b2`, whether `bar<N – 2>`’s unqualified-ness in `bar<N - 2>::num` caused the lookup to get `num` through `::bar<0>::num`, and *not through `b2`’s `bar<0>` base subobject (i.e. `this->bar<0>::num`)*. Is my question phrased incorrectly?(not being sarcastic). Should I change the italicized to “not through the injected name of the `bar<0>` base subobject”? I know the distinction between how `num` is accessed is moot because there's only one instance.I know `this->` is moot because of inaccessibility.

Comment: @CodeBricks Yes, `b2` has a `bar<1>` subobject and `bar<0>` has a `base` subobject. But these do not matter for name lookup. Names are not looked up through objects, names can only refer to an object (`int x;` there's an object of type `int` and `x` refers to that object). For a non-template class, an unqualified `bar<N-2>` would be looked up (also) in the base class scopes. As the class template `bar`'s base class is dependent, it is not considered *for unqualified lookup*. If it were qualified `something::bar<N-2>::num`, *only* the scope of `something` would be searched.

Comment: @CodeBricks As it turns out, my reasoning was wrong for the template case: The base class scope is indeed not searched, but the injected-class-name of a template can be used as a template-name. So inheritance is irrelevant for this example. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a good explanation of why private inheritance is not like public and protected inheritance, see two good answers from [private inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576978/private-inheritance).

> From a common understanding of inheritance, C++’ “private inheritance”
>   is a horrible misnomer: it is not inheritance (as far as everything
>   outside of the class is concerned) but a complete implementation
>   detail of the class.
>
> Seen from the outside, private inheritance is actually pretty much the
>   same as composition. Only on the inside of the class do you get
>   special syntax that is more reminiscent of inheritance than
>   composition.
>
> There’s a caveat though: C++ syntactically treats this as inheritance,
>   with all the benefits and problems that this entails, such as scope
>   visibility and accessibility. Furthermore, C-style casts (but no C++
>   cast!) actually ignores visibility and thus succeeds in casting your
>   Derived pointer to Base:
>
> `Base* bPtr = (Base*) new Derived();`
>
> Needless to say, this is evil.
>
> ---
>
> Public inheritance means that everyone knows that Derived is derived
>   from Base.
>
> Protected inheritance means that only Derived, friends of Derived, and
>   classes derived from Derived know that Derived is derived from Base.*
>
> Private inheritance means that only Derived and friends of Derived
>   know that Derived is derived from Base.
>
> Since you have used private inheritance, your main() function has no
>   clue about the derivation from base, hence can't assign the pointer.
>
> Private inheritance is usually used to fulfill the
>   "is-implemented-in-terms-of" relationship. One example might be that
>   Base exposes a virtual function that you need to override -- and thus
>   must be inherited from -- but you don't want clients to know that you
>   have that inheritance relationship.

As well as [Inaccessible type due to private inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011090/inaccessible-type-due-to-private-inheritance).

> This is due to the injected class name from A hiding the global A
>   inside C. Although A is visible, it is not accessible (since it is
>   imported as private), hence the error. You can access A by looking it
>   up in the global namespace:
>
> `void foo(::A const& a) {}`

So for example, this will work:

```
class GrandChild;
struct GrandParent { enum {n = 0}; };

struct Parent : private GrandParent { 
   enum {n = 1}; 
   friend GrandChild; 
};

struct GrandChild : private Parent {
    void f() {cout << GrandParent::n << endl;}
};
```

Otherwise you need to use global scope or the `using` directive to bring `::GrandParent` into scope.

Comment: +1. Your links and example of `friend` injection are helpful, but the accepted answer addressed my questions most directly.